# Prepend some innerHTML to a div in Native Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me on this question; I have only recently started coding in Javascript and for this reason I would like a strong foundation before breaking into jQuery.

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var app = {
  text: document.getElementById('text'),
  output: document.getElementById('output'),
  createDiv: document.createElement('div')
};

function postData(){
  app.output[0].appendChild(app.createDiv.firstChild);
  app.createDiv.classname = 'text';
  document.getElementsByClassName('username').innerHTML += app.text.value;
}
```

onClick I want the value of app.text to print (using innerHTML) ABOVE the output div. Any ideas or questions? Sorry if I am being vague or not making sense, I have been staring at this for 4 hours now and am probably just burned out!

Comment: What's your representative HTML? Can you show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), which illustrates what you're working with?

Comment: `app.createDiv.firstChild` doesn't exist. You created the DIV, but never gave it any children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a text node and insert it before each element in the NodeList returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```
var node = document.createTextNode(app.text.value);
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('username');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var elem = elements[i];
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(), elem)
}
```

And just to tempt you with the jQuery version:

```
$('.username').before(app.text.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I see the following problems with your code:

- `app.output[0]`: there should be no `[0]`, `app.output` is already an element (you got it by id). So use `app.output.appendChild(app.createDiv.firstChild);`. Still, this makes no sense; [as Barmar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280957/prepend-some-innerhtml-to-a-div-in-native-javascript#comment26817207_18280957), you just created that div, so it doesn't have any children at that point.
- `app.createDiv.classname`: should be `className`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('username').innerHTML`: this returns multiple elements, maybe you want `document.getElementsByClassName('username')[0].innerHTML`?